# OSX AppleScript mount SMB Share using the Guest user

Tags: macos, script, smb

How do I mount a SMB share using the guest user?

I know how to do it with an AFP share: `mount volume "afp://;AUTH=NO%20USER%20AUTHENT@NAS_AB01(AFP)._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Images"`

How do you do it with an **SMB** share?

Comment: What version of OS X?

Comment: `man mount_smbfs` on OS X 10.8 has the following example: `mount -t smbfs //guest:@myserver/PUBLIC /smb/public`. Does this work? You could run this from AppleScript using `do shell script`

Comment: `mount volume "smb://server/share"` uses the cached user credentials, if they exist, otherwise opens the credentials dialog. `mount volume "smb://guest:@server/share"` always opens the credentials dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a password after the `username` separated by a colon `:`.

With password:

```
mount volume "smb://username:password@server/share"
```

Without password:

```
mount volume "smb://username:@server/share"
```